# Change data in column based on vlookup vba between multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have data in column H in sheet "Example" that I would like to change based on the results of a vlookup to sheet "List".

So the vlookup would be: =VLOOKUP(H23,List!A:C,3,0).

However, I have another macro that I'm calling in this workbook, so I'd like to combine several vba macros into one.

So I'd like the data in column H in sheet "Example" to update based on the results of the vlookup to sheet "List".

Is that possible?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the corresponding [VLookup()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx) function in VBA:

```
' ITERATE THROUGH EACH ROW OF COLUMN H
For i = 1 to lastrowinColB
  Sheets("Example").Range("H" & i)= Application.VLookup( _
                                      Sheets("Example").Range("H23"), _
                                      Sheets("List").Range("A1:C500"),3,0)

Next i
```

Adjust above as needed. I bound the lookup array `A1:C500` instead of `A:C` that may have VBA run to millionth limit row. Also, check reference of lookup value `H23` as it may be circular reasoning, considering you intend to update values in column H.